# can I use a http string from another website like a document object?

Tags: greasemonkey

I am pulling a bunch of http source code from another website into my code; I now want to use it like document and do stuff like .getElementByID, etc. However, it's a string and my attempts at converting it to an object do not work. I'd rather not sift through the string manually, so any help would be great. Closest I got from another solution converted it to an xmlhttp object, but it still did not work. I am using:

https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest

- to pull in the code.

Thanks

Comment: This question may be useful as a search target since the title terminology is different than the dupe.